# Reserva de memoria con std::vector resize

Tags: c++, c++11

para una estructura de datos `std::vector<3Dpoint> v;` con `3Dpoint`:

```
struct 3Dpoint { 
    float x, y, z; 
    3Dpoint(float _x, float _y, float _z){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
}};
```

Intento redimensionar el tamaño del vector `v`, mediante `v.resize(m*n);`. Mi intención es reservar `m*n` estructuras `3Dpoint`. 
Al hacerlo obtengo el  `error: no matching function for call to ‘Punto3D::Punto3D()’`.
¿Cómo podria redimensionar este vector? 
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

`resize( )` **necesita** un constructor por defecto. Si el tamaño que pides es **mayor** que el tamaño actual del vector, este *insertará* elementos *por defecto*, llamando a dicho constructor.

Si lo que quieres es **garantizar que tengas espacio** para `m * n` elementos, **sin insertarlos** (es decir, haciendo que el `vector` **reserve memoria para ellos**), lo correcto es hacer

```
vector.reserve( m * n );
```

Haciendolo así, te aseguras que el vector **no llamará al *allocator* mas de 1 vez**, con lo que consigues toda la memoria necesaria *de golpe*, sin *insertar* nada en el `vector`.

Si lo que quieres es, no obstante, añadir `m * n` elementos **ya construidos**, no tienes mas que modificar el constructor de tu clase:

```
struct 3Dpoint { 
    float x, y, z; 
    3Dpoint( float _x = 0.0f, float _y = 0.0f, float _z = 0.0f ) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
} };
```

O, si te resulta mas cómodo, puedes dejar que el compilador lo haga por tí:

```
struct 3Dpoint { 
    float x, y, z; 
    3Dpoint( ) = default;
    3Dpoint( float _x, float _y, float _z ) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
} };
```

El resultado es el mismo: las variables `x, y, z` quedan a `0.0f`.